# Need help about redirecting views in Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, redirect, django-views

I'm a beginner in learning Django and have met with an issue that need everyone help.

I'm working on a web application for reading novels. I met with an issue that is related to views redirecting in Django. It's about how I can open the chapter page that I clicked on and read it perfectly normal but when I want to return to the novel index page by clicking on the link, I'm met with a NoReverseMatch error. I'll post my code below:

This is what I configured in the urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then I created and configured the urls.py like this:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home),
        path('book/<slug:book_slug>/<slug:chapter_slug>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
        path('genre/<slug:category_slug>', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
        path('book/<slug:book_slug>', views.book_detail, name='book_detail'),
        path('<slug:book_slug>/', views.book_detail, name='book_detail'),
        path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
        path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="app/login.html"), name="login"),
        path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'),name='logout'),
]
```

And this is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .models import Book, Category, Chapter
from gtts import gTTS
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    recommended_book = Book.objects.filter(recommended_book = True)
    recommended_book_hot = Book.objects.filter(recommended_book_hot = True)
    recommended_book_new = Book.objects.filter(recommended_book_new = True)
    recommended_book_finish = Book.objects.filter(recommended_book_finish = True)
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'recommended_book': recommended_book, 'recommended_book_hot': recommended_book_hot, 'recommended_book_new': recommended_book_new, 'recommended_book_finish': recommended_book_finish})
def detail(request, book_slug, chapter_slug):
    book = get_object_or_404(Chapter, book__slug = book_slug,slug = chapter_slug)
    title = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/detail.html', {'detail': book, 'title':title})
def register(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', {'form': form})
def category_detail(request, category_slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug = category_slug)
    return render(request, 'app/genre_detail.html', {'category':category})
def book_detail(request, book_slug):
    book = Book.objects.get(slug = book_slug)
    book_category = book.category.first()
    similar_books = Book.objects.filter(category__name__startswith = book_category)
    return render(request, 'app/book_detail.html', {'book': book, 'similar_books': similar_books, 'book_category': book_category})
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    books = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='books')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter = models.Count
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name = 'Books')
    detail = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter_name
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'images/', blank= True, null = True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    #date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    recommended_book = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recommended_book_hot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recommended_book_new = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recommended_book_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The part that I've met with issue is an Html page for viewing chapter:

```
<div class="bg-white text-gray">
            <div class="container p-2">
                <a href="/ " class="text-dark">Home  </a>/
                <a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.slug %}" class="text-dark">{{detail.book}}</a>/
                <a href="" class="text-dark">{{detail.chapter_name}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Through the config in urls.py, I can open a novel index page at `localhost/book/book.slug`, then read a chapter at `localhost/book/book.slug/chapter.slug`. Everything worked normally up to this part. After that, I want to return to the index page by clicking on the link I set at the top corner which back to `book/book.slug` again but was met with a NoReveseMatching error.

What I could inferred from the error logs was that I should have had an argument that is 'book.slug' such as '(book-1,)' for book_detail() to redirect to index page. But what happened was the argurment had a blank'('',)' instead which lead to said error.

Anyone have an idea of what I did wrong ? Any helps or suggestions are appreciated

Comment: First, keep your code cleaner with spaces wherever you can.

Also, in the second href tag, mind if you can enter some space like this and then try :

`book/{% url book.slug %}`

Lastly, in the same href tag, why not interpolated `{{ detail }}` instead of what you have done ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for asnwering. For your first suggestion, it's because I just keep piling codes due to looking for guides everywhere which made them look messy. I'll clean them up afterward. For your question, can you explain more on how i can interpolate {{ detail }} ? I just learn django recently so all the terms are still unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: I did try to paste the code at first try but couldn't post due to indents so had to use image temporarily at the moment. I'll try to edit and paste the code again. Thank you for sending me the document link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correction of `url`

You can pass url in django html like this...

```
href='{% 'book' book.slug %}'

-------- OR ---------

href='book/book.slug/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The url templatetag takes the name of the url (i.e. the value you pass to the `name` parameter when you define the path) as its first argument. If the url path itself requires args, those then get included in the url templatetag after the name.

It looks like you're trying to link to the first path that's named 'book_detail'? If that's the case, you would use `{% url 'book_detail' book.slug %}`.

[Read the url templatetag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for a better understanding of how it works.

Also, you have two different paths both with the name 'book_detail'. Path names should be unique within a single app.

Finally, you should put your code directly into the body of your question rather than including screenshots.